# How can I close bufio.Reader/Writer in golang?

Tags: go

How can I close `bufio.Reader` or `bufio.Writer` in golang?

```
func init(){
    file,_ := os.Create("result.txt")
    writer = bufio.NewWriter(file)
}
```

Should I close `Writer`? or just use `file.Close()` will make `Writer` close?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't close the `bufio.Writer`.

What you do is to `Flush()` the `bufio.Writer` and then `Close()` the `os.Writer`:

```
writer.Flush()
file.Close()
```

Comment: Yes, always flush, it has bitten me in a small project.

Comment: And remember that you can do `w := bufio.NewWriter...;` `defer w.Flush()`

Comment: @ThomasAhle Is that a good idea to ignore the error from w.Flush ?

Comment: @Shanicky_C if you want to do more advanced cleaning, you can `defer clean(w) ` or so.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following is canonical:

```
func doSomething(filename string){
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    // check err
    defer file.Close()
    writer = bufio.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    // use writer here
}
```

Comment: Is the writer.Flush() guaranteed to run before the file.Close()?  If not, what happens if the file is closed before the writer is flushed?

Comment: `defer` order is specified in golang, last-in-first-out.